# Copy and paste range to new destination

Tags: vba, excel

The function I'm trying to build into my spreadsheet is 'copy selected range and past to new range then every time I run the macro it will carry out the same copy.paste.range to new range but paste destination will follow on from previous pasted values. The function is collection stats on a weekly basis and the macro will automate the date collection.

I had the initial step working but its pasting formulas instead of just the values. I’ve added the paste special function but it’s not working at all now. Once this has been pasted in I’m looking for the next copy and paste to follow on from the data pasted into D21:J27 e.g. D28:J34 (Offset maybe?)

```
Sub CopyPaste_Weeklys()
Sheets("MI Build").Range("D7:J13").Copy
Sheets("MI Build").Activate
Range("D21:J27").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNoneActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Gary

Comment: Please show the code you have, it is hard to help without more specific information

Comment: Please show your tries in the code that you are trying to build. Describe any problems that you have encountered in your efforts.

Comment: the code needs to be put in the original post using [edit].  Do not put information that clarifies the problem in the comments.

Comment: Using copy/paste to transfer values is the wrong tool in VBA. Instead, just use something like `target.Value = source.Value`, where `source` and `target` are two range variables which have been set to the appropriate ranges. Among other things, this approach avoids having to use `Selection` and `Activate` (which are seldom needed in VBA).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is copy the value in `D7:J13` to `D21:J27`, your entire sub can be replaced by:

```
Sub CopyPaste_Weeklys()
    Sheets("MI Build").Range("D21:J27").Value = Sheets("MI Build").Range("D7:J13").Value
End Sub
```

In VBA, copy/paste should be reserved for situations where you need to copy things like formulas and formats. For values it is better to just use the `Value` property of the respective ranges.

Presumably the ranges are not always `D7:J13` and `D21:J27`, but your question provides no information as to how the ranges are to be determined. The fixed ranges above can be replaced by range variables that can be set at run time. Something on the following lines:

```
Sub CopyPaste_Weeklys()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim target As Range
    With Sheets("MI Build")
        i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Set target = Range(.Cells(i, "D"), .Cells(i + 6, "J"))
        target.Value = .Range("D7:J13").Value
    End With
End Sub
```

The variable `i` is determined by a standard Excel VBA trick to determine the row number of the last row in a columns which contains data.

Comment: Would you have any idea how to offset the paste every time the macro is run John? Thanks

Comment: By "offset the paste" do you mean to paste the data so that it is directly below the previous data? (so that e.g. the data is copied into `D21:J27` on one run and then into `D28:J34` the next? If so, is `D7:J13` always the source?

Comment: That works perfectly. Thankyou so much for your support.